# Prolog "append_dl/3" wrapper

Tags: prolog, difference-lists

I am just learning Prolog and the concept of difference-lists in Prolog, so bear with me please.

I have following code:

```
:- op(400, xfx, \).

append(Xs, Ys, Zs) :-
  append_dl( [Xs|T1]\T1, [Ys|T2]\T2, Zs\[]).

append_dl( Xs\Ys, Ys\Zs, Xs\Zs).
```

Now if i append Lists [1,2,3] and [a,b,c] in the SWI-interpreter it yields lists of lists

```
?- append([1,2,3],[a,b,c],Zs).
Zs = [[1, 2, 3], [a, b, c]].
```

Whereas if i do call append_dl direktly like so:

```
?- append_dl([1,2,3|T1]\T1,[a,b,c|T2]\T2,Zs\[]).
T1 = [a, b, c],
T2 = [],
Zs = [1, 2, 3, a, b, c].
```

it works...

What am i doing wrong and how should one wrap these functions using difference lists correctly?

Thank you guys for the Help :D

Comment: To your problem.... the issue is that your indirect call to `append([1,2,3],[a,b,c],Zs).` is actually calling `append_dl([[1,2,3]|T1]\T1, [[a,b,c]|T2]\T2, Zs\[]).` not `append_dl([1,2,3|T1]\T1, [a,b,c|T2]\T2, Zs\[]).`. Thus, the inconsistent results.

Comment: Ahh Ok I see. Thank you :D

Comment: Fixing the format of my prior comment... FYI, you don't need to define \ as an operator. The \ is an "older" way of delimiting a difference list. A hyphen (-) is often found in newer literature, *e.g.*, `append_dl(Xs-Ys, Ys-Zs, Xs-Zs).`

Comment: Seriously: That approach to learning this coding technique leads to nowhere! Rather start using [tag:dcg]s, **and then** study the particular encoding of grammar rules.  The example is taken from Program 15.2 of the Art of Prolog, but the rule for `append/3` is not.  It's just fantasy that does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this programming technique is key to Prolog, this `append_dl/3`  is an highly artificial example that nobody uses in this precise way. There is a Prolog textbook (Art of Prolog) which uses this as the first "motivating" example and some courses still follow such textbooks literally...

(Let's keep the common definition of [`append/3`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append) as it is usually defined)

*Difference-lists* are not lists. Rather, they are differences between lists. So *list difference* would be a more appropriate name for them. In most situations you do not have such differences ready, rather, you would have to convert an actual list to such a difference or (more commonly) construct the difference while you go along.

So take the list `[1,2,3]` which can be represented by the difference `[1,2,3|Xs]\Xs`. Another way to represent it would be `[1,2,3]\[]`. But you  can use `append_dl/3` only if the differences are represented in their most general form which you have not. Thus you first need to convert regular lists into that representation.

```
mappend(XsL, YsL, ZsL) :-
   append(XsL, Xs,Xs0),       % convert XsL to a difference Xs0\Xs
   append(YsL, Ys,Ys0),       % convert YsL to a difference Ys0\Ys
   append_dl( Xs0\Xs, Ys0\Ys, ZsL\[]).
```

In this concrete example, the conversion was just overhead. You needed the built-in [`append/3`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append) twice.  Also, `mappend(XsL, YsL, [1,2])` does not terminate, whereas `append(XsL, YsL, [1,2])` does.  For that case you would have change the order of the goals.

After you have given in that assignment, I would recommend you study Prolog's [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) notation.